# $('body').on('click', '.anything', function(){})

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('body').on('click', '.anything', function() {
    //code
});
```

doesn't work for anything right now and I can't figure out why. I'm able to anchor to anything else, say I just toss a `#wrap` div right inside the `body`. Then I'm able to do

```
$('#wrap').on('click', '.anything', function() {
    //code
});
```

for any element I want.

Any idea what I could have done to disable this ability on the body element?

Thanks!

Comment: have you got an `event.stopPropagation()` or `return false` in a click-handler between the element you're clicking and the `body` element?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Could you set up a http://jsfiddle.net demo? There must be something happening on your page that isn't included in the question.

Comment: so do you want to make some function related with click event on body not applicable / unavailable to some <div> or something in it?

Comment: @pimvdb  know it's not reproducible. Need help figuring out where to stat looking, part of a bigger codebase.

Comment: If it’s a big codebase then maybe there’s a `$('body').off('click')` later in the code. Try installing FireQuery into Firefox/Firebug to see if the binding has happened? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firequery/

Comment: _"Any idea what I could have done to disable this ability"_ - Are you saying the code _was_ working at one stage, but then it stopped working?

Comment: Try replacing `body` in the selector with `html` or `document` (without quotes), and see if that solves the problem ?

Comment: Did you try to check on other browsers?

Comment: @adeneo - Switching to html helped me but why should that be the case?

Comment: It depends on some outer context. When this has happened to me, it has been because the body element was not yet loaded (i.e. the script is called in the header, and the body element is not ready yet). So html is safer because it always loads before such scripts.

To those wondering why the action is attached to something like body or html, it is because this allows for dynamic elements (i.e. your button isn't on the page at the beginning). The listeners are 'attached' when the script is first executed, and if your attachment point isn't there yet, it won't work even when you add it later.

Answer (score 47):

You should use `$(document)`. It is a function trigger for any click event in the document. Then inside you can use the jquery `on("click","body *",somefunction)`, where the second argument specifies which specific element to target. In this case every element inside the body.

```
$(document).on('click','body *',function(){
    //  $(this) = your current element that clicked.
    // additional code
});
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan thanks for making me correct. i don't explain much because i m not native english speaker and my english is not well. but i tried my best.

Comment: I understand, I edited the English in your post to be a little clearer now. Generally people will edit posts to improve them like that so I encourage you to explain code even if you're worried about the quality of your English.

Comment: Thanks you so much @SuperBiasedMan

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

You must follow the following format

```
    $('element,id,class').on('click', function(){....});
```

****JQuery code****

```
    $('body').addClass('.anything').on('click', function(){
      //do some code here i.e
      alert("ok");
    });
```

Comment: @fancy seems forgot to response to your question. Please have a close look to my solution. It may me helpful.

Answer (score -10):

If you want to capture click on everything then do

```
$("*").click(function(){
//code here
}
```

I use this for selector: http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

This is used for handling clicks: http://api.jquery.com/click/

And then use http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

To stop normal clicking actions.

Comment: This adds a handler to every element in the DOM, which is heavy on the browser.

Comment: Further to what Joseph said, the example code in the question would (if not for the mysterious problem) call the handler only when the clicked element matches the `'.anything'` selector. Regarding your comment "and mobile hasn't been said", if it's a public website it will get accessed from mobile devices - the OP shouldn't need to spell this out explicitly.

Comment: Additionally,  if an element is 10 levels deep, since that code is attached to *all* elements, it fires 10 times - one for the element and 9 for its parents?