# Event Binding on Dynamically Created Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just begun my exploration of javascript and jquery, and would sincerely appreciate any help with my current dilemma.  The feature that I am trying to build involves a number of steps:

1. The 'enter' key triggers an event.
2. The appropriate value ('About', 'Contact', or 'Extra') within the input field will open a new page.
3. The input field (residing within a `<p>` element) is then cloned and inserted, allowing the user to input another value.

My dilemma involves binding.  Once the input field has been cloned, the page that was first opened will continue to open regardless of a new input value.  Meaning, if the 'About' page was first opened, then the 'About' page will continue to open even when a new value ('Contact' or 'Extra') is added to the inserted input field.  Here is the code that I have written:

*javascript*

```
$(function() {

  function cloneInput() {
    var clonedElement = $("p").last().clone(true);
    $("input").last().prop("disabled", true);
    clonedElement.insertAfter($("p").last()).prop("id", "seven");
    $("input").last().prop("value", "").focus();
  }

  $("#input-text").keydown(function(event) {
    var keypressed = event.keyCode || event.which;
    var text = $("#input-text").val();
    if (keypressed == 13) {
      if (text == "About") {
        window.open("about.html", "_blank");
        cloneInput();
      } else if (text == "Contact") {
        window.open("contact.html", "_blank");
        cloneInput();
      } else if (text == "Extra") {
        window.open("extra.html", "_blank");
        cloneInput();
      } else {
        $("<p>Command not found</p>").insertAfter("#six").prop("id", "error");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

*html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="index-body">
    <p id="one">Hello friend. My name is $%^&*$^%. Welcome to #@$%%%*&.</p>
    <p id="two">To learn more, please enter a command:</p>
    <p id="three">> About</p>
    <p id="four">> Contact</p>
    <p id="five">> Extra</p>
    <p id="six">> %<input type="text" maxlength="40" autofocus id="input-text"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

*result*

```
<p id="six">
  <input type="text" maxlength="40" autofocus id="input-text" disabled>
</p>
<p id="seven">
  <input type="text" maxlength="40" autofocus id="input-text">
</p>
```

I have searched stackoverflow and learned about .on(), .off(), and .change().  In addition, I have utilized these methods when refactoring my code.  Still, I cannot find a solution.  Thank you in advance.

*Note: I am aware that my naming conventions need to be cleaned up*.

Comment: if you paste html also will help to provide solution..

Comment: Thank you, @BEJGAMSHIVAPRASAD.  I have updated my post.

Comment: Can you paste what the HTML on the page looks like after a command entry? Based on the code I almost feel like I'd expect to see two input fields both with the same id, which probably isn't what you're expecting to have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is  looking good only one issue is accessing filed value instead of $('#input-text').val() use $(this).val() always gets current element value..

```js
$(function() {

      function cloneInput() {
        var clonedElement = $("p").last().clone(true);
        $("input").last().prop("disabled", true);
        clonedElement.insertAfter($("p").last()).prop("id", "seven");
        $("input").last().prop("value", "").focus();
      }

      $("#input-text").keydown(function(event) {
        var keypressed = event.keyCode || event.which;
        var text = $(this).val();
        if (keypressed == 13) {
          if (text == "About") {
            window.open("about.html", "_blank");
            cloneInput();
          } else if (text == "Contact") {
            window.open("contact.html", "_blank");
            cloneInput();
          } else if (text == "Extra") {
            window.open("extra.html", "_blank");
            cloneInput();
          } else {
            $("<p>Command not found</p>").insertAfter("#six").prop("id", "error");
          }
        }
      });

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a function on dynamically created elements, you should use

```
$(document).on(<event>, <object>, function(event) {

});
```

Example : This will perform the action on clicking the elements with class `class1` ( even on dynamically created elements )

```
$(document).on('click', '.class1', function(event) {
    /* do something here */
});
```

In your case :

```
$(document).on("click", "#input-text", function(event) {
var keypressed = event.keyCode || event.which;
var text = $("#input-text").val();
if (keypressed == 13) {
  if (text == "About") {
    window.open("about.html", "_blank");
    cloneInput();
  } else if (text == "Contact") {
    window.open("contact.html", "_blank");
    cloneInput();
  } else if (text == "Extra") {
    window.open("extra.html", "_blank");
    cloneInput();
  } else {
    $("<p>Command not found</p>").insertAfter("#six").prop("id", "error");
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I used this solution in combination with what  @BEJGAMSHIVAPRASAD provided.

Answer (score 1):

bind your event on document itself not on the element you want to trigger

```
$(document).on('keydown', "#input-text", function(event) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // all your code..
});
```

[**see my other answer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921450/body-onclick-anything-function/32066793#32066793)

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I used this solution in combination with what @BEJGAMSHIVAPRASAD provided.